# Codeigniter Redirect to a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, controller

I have different types of users with different functionalities, i want to redirect different users to their controllers,Is this a good practice in Codeigniter if yes how can i do that?

```
public function login() {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) {
                $db_data = array();
                $db_data['email'] = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
                $db_data['password'] = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);
                $res = $this->Fypms_model->auth_user($db_data);
                if ($res->result_id->num_rows == 1) {
                    //$this->session->set_userdata($user);
                    $res = $res->result();
                    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $res[0]->user_id);
                    //redirect("users/changepassword");

                    switch ($res[0]->user_type) {
                        case "SA":
                            redirect("/superadmin/index");;
                            break;

                    }
                } else {
                    $data['error'] = "Invalid Email or Password";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your redirect url in `if($res[0]->user_type== 'user type'){redirect("url");}` condition. use `elseif($res[0]->user_type== 'user type'){redirect("url");}` followed by first if condition.

Comment: I know how to use if else, i used switch statement because my system has 5 users.

Answer (score 0):

It depends to your system and your self, if you have huge system that can split into sub systems , you can do it , but if you have little system , you dont need to do that , only manage your user with permissions , and sessions.

if you want to use method 1:
you must add url helper then you can write easily:

`redirect('/controller/method');`

in method 2:

use session to manage users.